# javascript iterating through pairs of logically connected elements

Tags: javascript

I have a website with a series of empty text fields that the user can edit. Next to each text field is a check box as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="textfield1" size="60" /><input type="checkbox"> <br />
<input type="text" id="textfield2" size="60" /><input type="checkbox"> <br />
<input type="text" id="textfield3" size="60" /><input type="checkbox"> <br />
```

Once a user clicks submit, is there a way of iterating through the textinput and checkbox pair on a line by line basis?

for example, is it possible to somehow group the textfield and check box together and iterate through these groups going group.textfield.value =?  and group.checkbox.value = ?

I need an easy way to determine the text of a field and whether or not that particular field had it's check box selected

Comment: Note that form controls without a name can't be successful and won't be included when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the `text` inputs, and use `.nextSibling` to grab each adjacent `checkbox`.

Make sure you don't introduce any whitespace between them.

---

Another option is to group them in `fieldset` elements...

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" size="60" /><input type="checkbox">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" size="60" /><input type="checkbox">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" id="textfield3" size="60" /><input type="checkbox">
</fieldset>
```

...then iterate the `fieldset` elements, and use `.children[0]` and `.children[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Give each input a name (which they need anyway) that can be used to correlate the pairs:

```
<form onsubmit="doStuff(this);">
  <input type="text" id="textfield1" name="textfield1" size="60">
   <input type="checkbox" name="textfield1-cb"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="textfield2" name="textfield2" size="60">
   <input type="checkbox" name="textfield2-cb"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="textfield3" name="textfield3" size="60">
   <input type="checkbox" name="textfield3-cb"> <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doStuff(form) {
  var control, controls = form.elements;
  var pair;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];
    pair = form[control.name + '-cb'];

    if (control.type == 'text' && pair) {
      // control is the input and pair is the checkbox
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The above only requires the controls to be associated by name, not by structure, which should make it more robust.